# How to use subquery for further calculations?

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

How can I create a subquery for further calculation of DATEDIFF including another column(amount) and have an output for both DATEDIFF and X?

eg. **`ddate*amount/365*0.1 = X`**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *,
          DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)
          AS ddate 
          FROM contacts
          WHERE DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['ddate'] . "</td>";
    }
```

Comment: You mean another column in the same table?

Comment: Yes, another column from the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it directly, no need for subquery:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate) as NoOfDays,
      (DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate) * amount) / 365 * 0.1 as XAmount
      FROM contacts
      WHERE DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)>=1");
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you!

Is it possible that I could make 2 queries one displaying the DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)
and one displaying the output of that calculates the formula above?

Comment: You could create separate queries or you could create as ONE query like the one above. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, you can combine `INSERT` and `SELECT` with `DATEDIFF`. It would probably look like this: `INSERT INTO tbl (NoOfDays, Amount) SELECT DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate) as NoOfDays,(DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate) * amount) / 365 * 0.1 as XAmount FROM contacts WHERE DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)>=1`. See link [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) for reference.